# ¿Como verifico si un archivo tiene contenido o está vacío en Python?

Tags: python, archivo

Quiero escribir un contenido en un archivo usando los *métodos apropiados*, pero antes quiero verificar que el archivo al que quiero escribirle los datos esté completamente **vacío**.

¿Cómo verifico eso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haciendo uso de [os.stat](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat) para que por medio de `st_size` saber la cantidad de `bytes` en el archivo, sí es `0` está `vacío.`

```
import os
if os.stat("file").st_size == 0:
     print("Vacío")
```

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2507871)

```
# O así
f = open('archivo', 'w')
contenido = f.read()
if contenido=='':
   print("Vacío")
```

Comment: no hay otra manera que no sea esa? disculpa la pregunta, tu idea resolvio mi duda sin embargo esto es para una tarea y eso se ve muuy avanzado para lo que sabemos en el curso. Gracias de todos modos

Comment: La primera forma es la mejor a mi parecer para verificar si un archivo está vacío o no . La segunda es verificar si el contenido leído es vacío. es otra opción pero recomiendo la Primera

Comment: Cuidado que en el segundo ejemplo el abrir el archivo con modo 'w' lo trunca, además no se puede leer de un archivo abierto en modo escritura

Comment: Sería genial , que añadieran el porqué del -1 para esta respuesta. 3:)  para mejorar

Answer (score 2):

**La forma más sencilla para verificar el contenido de un archivo es mediante** **[os.stat()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat)** :

```
 import os
 #Si el tamaño es 0 significa que el contenido es vacio.
 os.stat('c:/myarchivo.txt').st_size == 0
```

Entonces podrías establecer una condición para determinar si el contenido de tu archivo es vacío.

```
import os
if os.stat('c:/myarchivo.txt').st_size == 0:
   print('El archivo esta vacío.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que comentas no quieres una forma "tan avanzada" creo que podría hacerse así: (Pero con muchos fallos)

```
archivo = open("vacio.txt", 'r')

vacio = True
for linea in archivo:
    if len(linea) > 0:
        vacio = False

archivo.close()

if vacio:
    print("El archivo está vacio")
else:
    print("El archivo contiene algo")
```