# directorios vacios en python

Tags: python

Quiero validar si un directorio 'carpeta' esta vació; Si esta vació borrarlo y si tiene algo no hacer nada.

Comment: muestra lo que has intentado aunque no funcione

Comment: Mira este hilo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/30666/como-verifico-si-un-archivo-tiene-contenido-o-est%C3%A1-vac%C3%ADo-en-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El siguiente codigo comprueba que el path existe con `os.path.exists()` y que efectivamente es un directorio con `os.path.isdir()`.

Si existe, con un `os.listdir()` comprobamos que este vacio, y si lo esta lo borramos.

```
'''
    Comprueba si existe un directorio y esta vacio y lo borra
'''    
import os
dirname = '\path\to\dir'

if os.path.exists(dirName) and os.path.isdir(dirName):
    if not os.listdir(dirName):
        print(f"Borrando directorio vacio {dirname}.")
        os.rmdir(dirname)
    else:    
        print(f"Directorio {dirname} no vacio.")
else:
    print(f"El directorio {dirname} no existe.")
```